# Creating an object using static members from a class

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I am creating a constructor which needs to get all the variables from another class. At the moment I have:

```
public class Person 
{
    public Person(Address.AddressDetails newAddress , string newTitle, string      newForname, string newSurname, string newTel,
                        string newMob, string newEmail)
        {
        }
        static public int ID;
        static public string Title;
        static public string Decorations;
        static public string Forename;
        static public string Surname;
        static public string Telephone;
        static public string Mobile;
        static public string Email;
        static public Address.AddressDetails Address;
}
```

The variables in the Address.AddressDetails are all static aswell.
How do I make Person.Address represent all the variables in the AddressDetails class?

Comment: Why are you using all static fields in combination with a regular constructor?

Comment: Having all these static public fields is very bad design. They will be shared across all instances of `Person` - what is the reason for this?

Comment: And copying over from other static fields is kind of strange too.

Comment: The reason for making them static is I am creating a windows phone 7 application and text from textboxes are being given to members in the class. For example: Person.Title = titleTextBox.Text

Answer (score -1):

In the constructor:

```
{
    Person.Adress = newAdress;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Person 
{
     public static Assign(Address.AddressDetails newAddress , string newTitle, string      newForname, string newSurname, string newTel,
                        string newMob, string newEmail) 
    {
        Address = newAddress;
        Email = newEmail;
        ....
        ... 

    }

     static private int ID;
     static private string Title;
     static private string Decorations;
     static private string Forename;
     static private string Surname;
     static private string Telephone;
     static private string Mobile;
     static private string Email;
     static private Address.AddressDetails Address;    

}
```

Something like this.

- make a `static public` method to assign a value
- make all members of the class `private`